# Get average column from two aggregated columns created by Group By

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have created a table using the below function

```
SELECT c.cus_code, cus_balance,
       SUM (line_units * line_price) AS "Total Purchases",
       COUNT (line_number) AS "Number of Purchases"
FROM customer c JOIN invoice i ON c.cus_code = i.cus_code
JOIN line l ON i.inv_number = l.inv_number
GROUP BY c.cus_code, cus_balance
ORDER BY cus_code;
```

Now, I want to expand this table by adding in a column `"Average Purchase"` by dividing the `"Total Purchases"/"Number of Purchases"` from the above Grouped By table result. I am having an issue implementing the final column since I need to calculate the final column using the Grouped By data.

Help?

Comment: You sure that query worked and not giving a  ambiguous column name error?? As the order by clause is using a colum name which exists in two tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another column like-

```
(SUM (line_units * line_price)*1.00)/(COUNT (line_number)) AS "Average Purchase"
```

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you just use `AVG()`?

```
SELECT c.cus_code, cus_balance,
       SUM(line_units * line_price) AS "Total Purchases",
       COUNT(line_number) AS "Number of Purchases",
       AVG(line_units * line_price) as "Average Purchase"
FROM customer c JOIN 
     invoice i
     ON c.cus_code = i.cus_code JOIN
     line l
     ON i.inv_number = l.inv_number
GROUP BY c.cus_code, cus_balance
ORDER BY cus_code;
```

This does assume that `line_number` is not `NULL`.  That seems like a reasonable assumption, but if it can be `NULL`, you might want to divide the expressions instead.

Comment: @NZ_DJ . . . This seems like the simplest solution.  I'm surprised you did not accept it.